# Cannot handle open collector output

Tags: bjt, pullup, proximity-sensor, open-collector

I have a sensor powered at 24VDC which has an open collector output

[image]

The output of the sensor (it is a PIR sensor), goes from 15Vdc when nothing is detected, and 0.7 Vdc when it detects some movement.

But the input of my mcu is always LOW, so it means that the Q10 is always conducting even when the voltage measured is 0.7 Vdc..

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Schematic is correct. Check the connection and test your transistor.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet of the sensor?

Comment: Most likely the 0.7V output when something is detected is high enough to keep the transistor on. Try changing the 100K to a lower value like 10K.